# What is the function $f(x)$ which is differentiable everywhere and $f(x-1)f(x-2)+1=f(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-equations

> What is the function $f(x)$ which is differentiable everywhere and $f(x-1)f(x-2)+1=f(x)$ and $f(1)=f(2)=1$ ?

I've been wondering about this problem for about $1 \frac{1}{2}$ years.
I don't know the tools to solve this problem. So, if you could show me how to find a solution, I would like that.

I found the values of $f(x)$ from $0$ to $10$:

$$0,1,1,2,3,7,22,155,3411,528706,1803416167,\dots,f(n)$$

I realized that at $f(-1)$ can't be found just using $f(x-1)f(x-2)+1=f(x)$ because $n\times f(0)=f(1)$ has infinite solutions. $f(-1)$ can't be zero because then $f(-2)$ wouldn't be defined because $n\times 0=-1$. So maybe if I add $f(x)$ must differentiable everywhere I could get an answer.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A007660 is worth a look.

Comment: @BarryCipra cool there is a list my problem with the list is if $f(-1)=0$ then $f(-2)$ wouldn't be defined.

Comment: I think adding the "every where differentiable " condition is not a good idea since by differentiating both sides of the equation, we will get: $f(x-1)+f(x-2)=1$. (by assuming the domain of the function to be $\mathbb{R}$)

Comment: @Amirhossein what if it isn't all a real function? okay though a very good point

Comment: @DarkMain You mean, you want to change the domain?

Comment: @Amirhossein yes to complex numbers

Comment: Ok, and What is the condition on $f$ ?

Comment: You should state that explicitly in the post itself, is it $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$? Or $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$? Or perhaps something else?

Comment: If $f(0) = 0$, shouldn't it be a polynomial function with a factor $x$ ? I asked this because at $x = 0$, the function would evaluate to $0$.

Comment: @Sil I think he did mention the domain of the function (see the line : "I found that the values from $0$ to $10$")

Comment: @Sil, I think that he also mentioned the codomain as well in the question even if it didn't catch my eye all of a sudden.

Comment: Also, I think that the polynomial function should can have a form $f(x)  = x(x-1)(x-2) + 1$, since $f(1) = f(2) = 1$. But such a form only holds for $f(1)$ and $f(2)$, which means there is a need for a slight modification in the term before the plus sign in the form I suggested.

Comment: I don't suspect you will find a closed form for this sequence easily... An asymptotic form is given on oeis ($f(n)\sim c^{\phi^n}$, where $c\approx 1.113$ and $\phi$ is the golden ratio), but nothing more precise than that is listed.

Comment: @Amirhossein How did you get that from differentiating? I just get $f'(x-1)f(x-2)+f(x-1)f'(x-2)=f'(x)$ and I don't see how to cancel out all the $f'$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will prove the

### Statement

There is no continuous function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that it satisfies following conditions:

1. $\exists x \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f\left(x\right) = 0$;
2. $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$
   $$ f\left(x - 1\right)f\left(x\right) + 1 = f\left(x + 1\right)$$

### Proof

Assume that there is such $f$. Let $\mathbb{U}$ be the set of zeros of $f$. $\mathbb{U}$ is nonemtpy.
Let $u \in \mathbb{U}$. Then we have that
$$ f\left(u - 2\right)f\left(u - 1\right) = -1$$
Meaning that both $f\left(u - 2\right)$ and $f\left(u - 1\right)$ are nonzero and have different signs. By continuity there exists
$$\mathbb{U} \ni u' \in \left(u - 2, u - 1\right)$$
Thus we have shown that for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ there is $u \in \mathbb{U}$ such $u < x$.

If $u \in \mathbb{U}$, then we have the following equalities:
$$\begin{align*}
f\left(u + 0\right) &= 0 \\
f\left(u + 1\right) &= 1 \\
f\left(u + 2\right) &= 1 \\
f\left(u + 3\right) &= 2 \\
f\left(u + n\right) &= a_{n + 1},\quad n \in \mathbb{N} \tag{1} \label{u+n}
\end{align*}$$
, where $a_{n}$ defined [here](https://oeis.org/A007660). From this sequence we only need to know that $a_{n}$ is non-decreasing and
$$ \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n} = +\infty \tag{2} \label{a_n}$$
By the Weierstrass theorem $f$ reaches its maximum $\mathsf{M} \in \mathbb{R}$ on $\left[0, 1\right]$. By \eqref{a_n} we can find $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a_{n} > \mathsf{M}$. Then we find $u \in \mathbb{U}$ and $m \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $-m \leq u \leq -m + 1 \leq -n$. It follows that $u + m \in \left[0, 1\right]$ and $m > n$. But by \eqref{u+n}
$$\begin{align*} \mathsf{M} &\geq f\left(u + m\right) \\
&\geq a_{m + 1} \\ 
&\geq a_{n} \\
&> \mathsf{M} \end{align*}$$
This completes the proof.

It follows that there is no function you are looking for, if it's defined like $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

P. S. English is not my native language. I apologize for any possible mistakes when writing the answer in English.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by Milten's comment, here's some dirty asymptotic calculation:

1. Approximate the original equation
   $$f(x) \approx f(x-1)f(x-2)$$
   Given the terms you have written, this approximation should be pretty good everywhere except for the first few terms
2. Let $g(x) = \log f(x)$. Then

$$g(x) = g(x-1) + g(x-2)$$

is a Fibonacci sequence. The [explicit form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Relation_to_the_golden_ratio) of this sequence is given by

$$g(x) = \frac{\phi^x-\psi^x}{\sqrt5}$$

where $\phi$ and $\psi$ are golden ratio and its square-conjugate. Since $\psi\approx-0.6$, it will asymptotically tend to zero, so the asymptotic behaviour of the approximated sequence will be

$$f(x) \approx \exp \frac{\phi^x}{\sqrt 5}$$

Probably this approach can be cleaned up by considering very precisely the first few initial values of the sequence $g(x)$ to obtain expressions precise to a desired order. Analytic closed-form expression likely does not exist, because the recursive identity combines both addition and multiplication.

Comment: It was good to see the asymptotics for this one, +1. I too think a closed form is out of the way. It may still be there but might require special functions.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Yep. I draw analogy with numerical methods, where one can evaluate functions with no closed-form solution, such as roots of a polynomial, by an iterative method which involves only multiplication and addition. So, in general, such equations need not possess closed-form solutions

Comment: @AleksejsFomins, nice answer (indeed better than mine !) - +1 for you.

Comment: @Spectre why better? I addressed asymptotics, and you were dealing with negative values. They are just different :)

Comment: @AleksejsFomins, I know it, but you did what I wasn't able to do. That makes me feel like voting up your answer. Congrats, sir ! :-D

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this will be of any help for solving this problem, but here it is:
We know $$f(x-1).f(x-2)+1 = f(x)\longrightarrow(1)$$ holds for every $x$ as per the question. Therefore,
$$f((x+1)-1).f((x+1)-2)+1 = f(x+1)\\
=f(x).f(x-1)+1 = f(x+1)\longrightarrow(2)$$
and
$$f((x+2)-1).f((x+2)-2)+1 = f(x+2)\\
=f(x+1).f(x)+1 = f(x+2)\longrightarrow(3)$$
$(2)- (1) =$
$$ f(x + 1) - f(x) = f(x - 1).(f(x) - f(x - 2))\longrightarrow(4)$$
Putting $x = 0$ in $(4)$, we get:
$$f(1) - f(0) = f(-1).(0 - f(-2))\\
1 = -f(-1).f(-2)\\
\implies f(-1) = \frac{-1}{f(-2)} \space\text{or}\space f(-2) = \frac{-1}{f(-1)}
\implies f(-1), f(-2) \space \text{could be non-zero real numbers}
$$
I tried to find their values, but ended up in erroneous calculations (I was half asleep when I did all these yesterday, a few minutes before midnight, so I had no sense of my path).

I feel that this is an additional clue to the values of $f(-1)$ and $f(-2)$, but I have no idea how much this would help.

I'd suggest that you wait till a proper answer is found. And please don't downvote my answer, I had to work even during midnight to find a way.

**EDIT $1$** :There was a simpler way to arrive here (see the comments below), but I described the path I took as well as just one inference I had.

**EDIT $2$**: Refer the answer below for a better answer.

Comment: If there's any mistake, please mention it in the comment box.

Comment: Wouldn't you be able to put it simply. From $$f(x-1)f(x-2)+1=f(x)$$Putting $x=2$, we get $f(0)=0$, and putting $x=0$, you get $f(-1)f(-2)+1=0$.

Comment: @Mourad yes, but I described only how I came to it.